MAUI modal navigation with PopModalAsync causes System.ArgumentException
I'm trying to handle navigation to a ContentPage from another ContentPage
MainView : PushModalAsync -> BrowseDatabasePage : PushModalAsync -> MimicPage : PopModalAsync
which then gives me this exception
System.ArgumentException:
 'Ambiguous routes matched for:
   //IMPL_LocalLAPTOP/IMPL_LocalLAPTOP/LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16
 matches found:
   //IMPL_LocalLAPTOP/IMPL_LocalLAPTOP/LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16,
   //IMPL_LocalLAPTOP/IMPL_LocalLAPTOP/LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16 Arg_ParamName_Name'

I did add some logging so I could see where in the navigation change I was and had been
Navigating
Source  : Push
Current : //LocalLAPTOP
Target  : D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16
Navigated
Source   : Push
Current  : //LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16
Previous : //LocalLAPTOP
Navigating
Source  : Push
Current : //LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16
Target  : D_FAULT_MimicPage17
Navigated
Source   : Push
Current  : //LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16/D_FAULT_MimicPage17
Previous : //LocalLAPTOP/D_FAULT_BrowseDatabasePage16

The main page displays the database view like this
this.DatabaseCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(
async () =>
{
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BrowseDatabasePage(new BrowseDatabaseViewModel(this.connection, this.server.ServerName, string.Empty)));
});

The View
.xaml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Mobile.Views.BrowseDatabasePage"
             x:DataType="vm:BrowseDatabaseViewModel"
             xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:Mobile.Resources"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Mobile.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Mobile_Connection;assembly=Mobile Connection"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <toolkit:SelectedItemEventArgsConverter x:Key="SelectedItemEventArgsConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Fill">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}" HorizontalOptions="Fill"
      SelectionMode="Single"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDatabaseItem}">
      <ListView.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
          EventName="ItemSelected"
          Command="{Binding ItemSelectedCommand}"
          EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource SelectedItemEventArgsConverter}" />
      </ListView.Behaviors>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell x:DataType="models:DatabaseItem">
            <Grid Padding="0, 10">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0" />
            </Grid>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

.cs
public partial class BrowseDatabasePage : ContentPage
{
  private readonly BrowseDatabaseViewModel viewModel;

  public BrowseDatabasePage(BrowseDatabaseViewModel vm)
  {
    this.viewModel = vm;

    this.InitializeComponent();
  
    HandlerChanged += this.OnHandlerChanged;

    this.viewModel.RefreshDatabaseCommand.Execute(this);
  }

  private void OnHandlerChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    HandlerChanged -= this.OnHandlerChanged;

    this.BindingContext = this.viewModel;
  }
}

ViewModel
public partial class BrowseDatabaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MobileClient connection;

    private string serverName;

    public BrowseDatabaseViewModel(MobileClient connection, string serverName, string groupName)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.serverName = serverName;

        this.GroupName = groupName;

        this.DatabaseItems = new ObservableCollection<DatabaseItem>();

        this.RefreshDatabaseCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(
        async () =>
        {
            await this.BrowseDatabase(this.GroupName);
        });
    }

    public int DatabaseItemCount => this.DatabaseItems.Count;

    public string DatabaseItemsParentName { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public DatabaseItem SelectedDatabaseItem { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<DatabaseItem> DatabaseItems { get; private set; }
    
    public IAsyncRelayCommand RefreshDatabaseCommand { get; private set; }

    public IAsyncRelayCommand GoBackCommand { get; private set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task ItemSelected(object item)
    {
        var databaseItem = item as DatabaseItem;

        if (databaseItem != null)
        {
            if (databaseItem.Type == "Mimic")
            {
                await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new MimicPage(new MimicViewModel(databaseItem, this.connection)));
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task BrowseDatabase(string groupName)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<DatabaseItem> browseResponse;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName))
        {
            browseResponse = await this.connection.Database.GetDatabaseRootAsync(this.serverName);
        }
        else
        {
            browseResponse = await this.connection.Database.GetHierarchicalChildrenOf(this.serverName, groupName);
        }

        this.DatabaseItems.Clear();

        foreach (var item in browseResponse)
        {
            this.DatabaseItems.Add(item);
        }

        this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.DatabaseItems)));
        this.PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(this.DatabaseItemCount)));
    }
}

BrowseDatabasePage has no route registered explicitly in code and I can't explain where the route with Arg_ParamName_Name has come from.

You're not showing any actual code. Please include everything that is relevant and provide a minimal reproducible example.

This occurs when you register your routes in XAML (in the Appshell file) and you also try registering your routes in code behind in C#. You can check if you register the Page's route twice.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT "BrowseDatabasePage has no route registered explicitly in code and I can't explain where the route with Arg_ParamName_Name has come from."

Did you check the route address? You can read this thread about the issue.

I did and I failed to find an instance of it happening. If this is the real cause considering the number of times that people are raising it and the fact that apparently it's not allowed perhaps an exception should be raised on attempting to register the same route twice.

await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BrowseDatabasePage(new BrowseDatabaseViewModel(this.connection, this.server.ServerName, string.Empty))); You can check this code and find if you create new route every time you navigate to new page.
